# How can I make a program that takes 3 seconds and then print in the console

Tags: python-3.x

The code below works at first but then I erased and retyped it and it doesn't work anymore. I don't know what is wrong but when I run it it should wait for 2 seconds and print s9 in the console, not print s first and print 9 two seconds later. I don't know what is wrong

I tried to add `flush=True` but it doesn't work

```
from time import sleep
print('s', end='')
sleep(2)
print(9)
```

I expect it will wait 2 seconds and print s9, not print s first and print 9 2 seconds later

Comment: You want `sleep(2); print('s9')`

Comment: what in the world is the question? :/

Answer (score 0):

Code is read in order. First line is read and executed, then the second, so on and so forth.

First, you import the `sleep()` method from the `time` module with `from time import sleep`.

Then, you print "s" without newline with `print('s', end='')`

Then you wait 2 seconds with `sleep(2)`

And finally you print "9" with a newline with `print(9)`.

However, it is not what you want. You want to first wait 2 seconds and then print "s" and "9". To do that, you just have to switch the order:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
print('s', end='')
print(9)
```

Even better, you can put the last two lines together :

```py
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
print("s9")
```

Comment: Well to be more precise, the whole code is read first in order to check for any syntax error or such, and then the lines are executed in order.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is running from the top to bottom.
So your part here:

```
print('s', end='')
sleep(2)
print(9)
```

First prints "s" then waits 2s and then prints 9. You can either move the first print below the sleep like this:

```
sleep(2)
print('s', end='')
print(9)
```

Or, like @rdas suggested, just print once:

```
from time import sleep

sleep(2)
print('s9')
```